# How can I solve TypeError: path.split is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typeerror, react-hook-form

Now I'm using [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/) for login validation.

But, **TypeError: path.split is not a function** errors continue to occur when
**ref={register}** is entered in input tag.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {useForm} from "react-hook-form";
import './Auth.css';

export default function Register() {

    const {register, errors, watch} = useForm();

    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" ref={register({ required: true})} />
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" />
                <label>Password Confirm</label>
                <input type="password"/>
                <input type="submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Even I copied and pasted the example code, the same error occurs, so how can I solve it?

The error code is as follows.
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you're using React Hook Form v7 with the v6 syntax, which is why you get that error.

Here is a similar issue: https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/4595

With the v7 you have to use `register` like that:

```js
<input type="email" {...register('email', { required: true })} />
```

Or install v6, documentation here: https://react-hook-form.com/v6/api#register

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<input placeholder="To" type="email" {...register('email', { required: true })} />
```